# Samsung stuck at boot Lineage OS boot animation after flashing GSI

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, boot

My device is Samsung Galaxy A9 2018 (SM-A920F), A/B and TWRP unsupported. Therefore, I combined system.img (Andy Yan's Lineage OS 18.1 A/B), vendor.img and boot.img (both are stock) into a single .tar file and flashed it via Odin. It booted and said "encryption was unsuccessful" and asked for factory reset. I did it, it rebooted and stuck at Lineage booting animation.
Does anyone know how to resolve it?

Comment: Interesting that I get to see my creation here. Nevertheless, you should try PHH's AOSP first before any other based on it, and also better luck asking in Telegram instead of here.

Comment: well yours is the only one that can boot up into the animation tho

Comment: by any chance fstab is broken by magisk?

Comment: fixed it by editing fstab.qcom to decrypt the phone